# What is the Effect of Multiplying a Function by the Unit Impulse Function in the Frequency Domain?

Tags: frequency-domain, dirac-delta-impulse

I know about the the shifting property of the impulse function in the time domain as can be seen in equation $(1)$.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\delta(x - a)dx = f(a)\tag{1}
$$

But what is the effect of multiplication of a function by the impulse function in the Frequency domain? I.e

$$
X(\omega) = \delta(\omega - \omega_0)\cdot H(\omega)
$$

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a slight typo in Robert Bristow-Johnson's answer. Should be

\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) e^{j \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}\omega\\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(\omega_0) \delta(\omega - \omega_0) e^{j \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}\omega\\
\\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2 \pi} H(\omega_0) e^{j \omega_0 t}
\end{align}

What this actually means is that during the inverse transform, $\delta(\omega - \omega_0)$ selects point frequency $\omega_0$ from the frequency response $H(\omega_0)$, and the value of $H(\omega_0)$ at that point determines the magnitude and phase of the time domain sinusoid $e^{j \omega_0 t}$.

Comment: thank you for spotting and fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

All it means is

$$\begin{align}
X(\omega) &=  H(\omega) \delta(\omega - \omega_0)\\
 &=  H(\omega_0) \delta(\omega - \omega_0) \\
\end{align}$$

which means, in the time domain

$$\begin{align}
x(t) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) e^{j \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}\omega\\
\\
 &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(\omega_0) \delta(\omega - \omega_0) e^{j \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}\omega\\
\\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2 \pi} H(\omega_0) e^{j \omega_0 t}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f(x)$ that is continuous at $x=x_0$ the following holds:

$$f(x)\delta(x-x_0)=f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)\tag{1}$$

So the result is a Dirac impulse at $x=x_0$ scaled by $f(x_0)$.

Comment: So is it the same in the frequency domain ie: 1) F(w)δ(w−w0) = f(w0)δ(w−w0),    Rather than: 2) F(w)δ(w−w0)  = F(w0). Therefore, is (1) the correct answer?

Comment: @John: Yes, the domain doesn't matter, Eq. (1) is valid regardless of the interpretation of the independent variable $x$. The Dirac impulse only "disappears" when you integrate (1), otherwise it doesn't.