# What is the Effect of Multiplying a Function by the Unit Impulse Function in the Frequency Domain?

Tags: frequency, fourier

[image: Shifting]

I know about the the shifting property of the impulse function in the time domain as can be seen in the picture.

But what is the effect of multiplication of a function by the impulse function in the Frequency domain.

ie: X(W) =  δ(w - w0)*H(w) = ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while there might be electrical engineers around which have the knowledge to answer this question, it's a complete math question and should go to the correct SE site.

Comment: there is a signal processing SE, go and ask there

Comment: Is there also an integral in the frequency domain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Effect of Multiplying a Function by the Unit Impulse Function in the Frequency Domain?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68076/what-is-the-effect-of-multiplying-a-function-by-the-unit-impulse-function-in-the)